# Android REQUEST_DENIED Google places API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on Android Google maps application but the query  string i am using to get results of places near by the user is not working.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=123.666,33.166&radius=50000&sensor=false&types=establishment&name=hotel&key={myKey}
```

I am using [this link to obtain a Maps API key](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android).

here is the response i am receiving.

```
      {
         "html_attributions" : [],
         "results" : [],
         "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate the Places API key via:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

More on this under:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#Authentication

HTH

Comment: ok i will try to generate key from this link as well......but previously i have generated link from link like this and it works https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: Is there any difference in generating KEY from each of these links.......I am using this for ANDROID Application.

Comment: Places API Web Service is not managed using the mapkey, but using the API console. The best explanation I found for this is offereed by this article: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/ HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you are using a wrong/old key. Lokk at your link, it's over 3 years old. Better try this way to obtain a new key: [Obtaining a Google Maps Android API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey). This is the official site.

Comment: I have tried this as well still have the same MD5 key as well as the same API key

Comment: using that API i have successfully able to draw map, but unable to feth data from maps.googleapis.com